# Google-diff-match avoid showing new lines?

Tags: javascript, diff

I am using diff-match http://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html

To show differences between 2 pieces of html. The problem is that the script shows new line as `¶`

Is there any way to set to don't show it?

Now I am just removing all istances of `\n` and `\r`, but this doesnt' sound good

Comment: It's been a long time since I did any work with Diff Match Patch because it has been rock solid in my implementation, but I don't remember the paragraph symbols being an issue. What have you tried?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you have seen in the documentation, the pretty html function is just a sample to develop some cool ui. However, of you replace the ¶ (& para;) with null in the function, the symbol will disappear.

```
  diff_match_patch.prototype.diff_prettyHtml = function(diffs) {
    var html = [];
    var pattern_amp = /&/g;
    var pattern_lt = /</g;
    var pattern_gt = />/g;
    var pattern_para = /\n/g;
    for (var x = 0; x < diffs.length; x++) {
      var op = diffs[x][0];    // Operation (insert, delete, equal)
      var data = diffs[x][1];  // Text of change.
      //var text = data.replace(pattern_amp, '&amp;').replace(pattern_lt, '&lt;')
      //    .replace(pattern_gt, '&gt;').replace(pattern_para, '&para;<br>');
      var text = data.replace(pattern_amp, '&amp;').replace(pattern_lt, '&lt;')
          .replace(pattern_gt, '&gt;').replace(pattern_para, '<br>');
      switch (op) {
        case DIFF_INSERT:
          html[x] = '<ins style="background:#e6ffe6;">' + text + '</ins>';
          break;
        case DIFF_DELETE:
          html[x] = '<del style="background:#ffe6e6;">' + text + '</del>';
          break;
        case DIFF_EQUAL:
          html[x] = '<span>' + text + '</span>';
          break;
      }
    }
    return html.join('');
  };
```

To test this, just go to the link you provided in Chrome and in console copy paste above function before hitting the compute diff button.

Comment: I haven't tried that.. I tought there was a setting +1 anyway

Comment: As I mentioned prettyHtml is just a convenience function. Author wants users to bake in their own ui. It wouldn't make sense to give configuration parameter for a convenience function. In fact, we just did a custom ui above. We can call this fn something else and start baking.

Comment: I went through this and ended up creating a wrapper library to help with the "presentation work" needed to use `diff_match_patch`: https://github.com/arnab/jQuery.PrettyTextDiff